# Restore woocommerce orders

Tags: posts, database, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

Recently my server team replaced my database and they put our previous Database .  So we lost our order details of one day[particular day] .  Now the server team give the backup that contain the lost day order details .

Now please tell how can i restore these orders ?

I cannot replace our database with the given backup , because today also we have orders .

Could anyone tell the step by step instruction ?

I Created a new database and uploaded backup .I understand that order are saved in wp_posts, and post meta .

So what i need to do ? , i export the all the order in that date from wp_posts,and post meta as sql file . Then just need to import it in to current database ? It make any problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Simple.

**Step 1:** Create a replica of the instance.

**Step 2:** Import the old .sql file which contained one day lost orders data.

**Step 3:** Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-simply-order-export/ plugin and export CSV or XML of 1 day data which you have lost.

**Step 4:** Install the above plugin in the LIVE instance and import the CSV or XML generated.

That's all.

Comment: Thank you :) . But friend , i didn't understand . could you please explain. "Create a replica of the instance." ???

Comment: @Ron: Create a replica of the instance means take a copy of the files of wordpress which you are using currently on localhost. Replica means a copy of original in which we will be importing a different SQL/DB

Comment: But i didn't think it is a good idea . Could you please give solution that depend on the sql queries ?

Comment: This is the best and fastest way by which you can solve this. You can also do this via SQL queries but this is so lengthy process and you need to create a PHP mapping script using your development knowledge.

Comment: But my total database size is upto 2 gb , and total file size is more than 10gb .

Comment: I will check this friend .

Comment: I have post some kind of similar solution (but different) in your duplicated thread over [stackoverflow in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234875/restore-woocommerce-orders/)